# Access a variable in Railtie initializer from other class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, railtie

I have a gem which has the following Railtie class.
I am trying to access my_config variable from outside, i.e another ruby class in the same gem. How can I access it?

```
module myModule
    module Rails
      class Railtie < ::Rails::Railtie

        initializer 'load_config' do
          my_config = "random config here"
          puts my_config
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use [instance_variable_get](http://http:/https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_get):

```
myModule::Rails::Railtie.new.instance_variable_get(:@my_config)
```